# Why cant I access my hosted Flask webApp via EC2 (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I successfully created a Flask app locally (Ubuntu) and wanted to host this app via amazon EC2. I copied all the files to aws and run the application via

```
(testVenv38) ubuntu@ip-xxx-yy-39-70:~/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/flaskTest$ python3 application.py
 * Serving Flask app "flaskTest" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: xxx-yyy-030
```

Afterwards I was expecting to access my application from any machine via the following link (yellow) followed by the "5000" from definition in my application.py

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

[image]

(yellow link is https://3.69.xyz.abc/5000), but I get no response. How can I make my app accessible for everybody?

Here is the whole log. But thats the same I get when I run it locally, so this does not indicate the problem I guess.

```
(testVenv38) ubuntu@ip-xxxx:~/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/flasklogin-tutorial-master$ python3 application.py
 * Serving Flask app "flask_login_tutorial" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: xxx
failed to send traces to Datadog Agent at http://localhost:8126
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 412, in call
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/internal/writer.py", line 356, in _send_payload
    response = self._put(payload, headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/internal/writer.py", line 332, in _put
    conn.request("PUT", self._endpoint, data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1007, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 947, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 918, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/internal/writer.py", line 458, in flush_queue
    self._retry_upload(self._send_payload, encoded, n_traces)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 409, in call
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 369, in iter
    six.raise_from(retry_exc, fut.exception())
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0x7f04d4bdfd60 state=finished raised ConnectionRefusedError>]
failed to send traces to Datadog Agent at http://localhost:8126
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 412, in call
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/internal/writer.py", line 356, in _send_payload
    response = self._put(payload, headers)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/internal/writer.py", line 332, in _put
    conn.request("PUT", self._endpoint, data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1007, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 947, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 918, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ddtrace/internal/writer.py", line 458, in flush_queue
    self._retry_upload(self._send_payload, encoded, n_traces)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 409, in call
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtuelleUmgebungen/testVenv38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 369, in iter
    six.raise_from(retry_exc, fut.exception())
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0x7f4c81faf490 state=finished raised ConnectionRefusedError>]
```

Edit2:

The opened ports (other than my own ip for ssh access) are the following:

```
Portbereich Protokoll   Quelle  Sicherheitsgruppen
Alle    Alle    sg-XXX7113746eda1a92    default
22  TCP 0.0.0.0/0   default
```

Edit3:

I added the following entry to incoming traffic:

```
0 - 65535   TCP 0.0.0.0/0   default
```

Still does not work.

Comment: Your link is broken, what you're getting when invoking the link?

Comment: @Sam How can i fix the link? I added the whole log after starting app. But thats the same I get when I start locally. Just indicating a small problem with tenacity.

Comment: Did you open the port in the security group assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: @MarkB I added the open ports (except the ones which belong to my own ip) to the original post.

Comment: You only listed port 22 as open in the security group. You need to add a rule to the security group opening port `5000`.

Comment: @MarkB I have to open it for tcp? I added the whole range (see edit), but still does not work.